# Collection View in tableview's prototype cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm working on this [tutorial](https://www.thorntech.com/2015/08/want-your-swift-app-to-scroll-in-two-directions-like-netflix-heres-how/#comment-6750).
So far I have created a `tableView` and inside the prototype cell, I have placed `collectionView`.

It's all working fine as showed in tutorial. But I want to go little further.

So My question is, How to have different number of collection items in each category(section).Should I have more than one prototype cell to achieve this? Please help me with this.

Comment: `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int)` specifies how many items are in the collectionview. You are probably using everywhere the same number that is why each row has same number of collectionView items.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment. Yeah it updates the same count in all category. But I want different number of collection items in each category For example: In Action - 10, Drama - 15, Other -20. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try maintaining an array that holds the number of items you want in each section.

And then inside below method just return that array[section].

```
- func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int)
```

Answer (score 0):

i agree with @jai prakash that you create a array of sections
eg. section["Action","Drama","Others"]

You can do this with number of section in collection view method of UICollectionView Delegate

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
return section.count
}
```

After this you can assign number of items in each section

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // here with condition you can assign number of Items in each section EG: for Action Section
    if section == 0
    {
        return 10
    }

}
```

and finally you can insert item in each section...